# AsyncAPI: Only generate payload

Tags: go, generator, asyncapi

Is it possible to skip generation of specific files using asyncapi-generator?

I am using the Go generator but I only need the `payload.go`. Right now it always generates all files:

`handlers.go  payloads.go  publishers.go  router.go  server.go  subscribers.go`

The command I am using is:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -it \
-v ${PWD}/asyncapi.yaml:/app/asyncapi.yml \
-v ${PWD}/output:/app/output \
asyncapi/generator -o /app/output /app/asyncapi.yml @asyncapi/go-watermill-template --force-write
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot selectively generate only selected files yet. I encourage you to [join the related discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/asyncapi/generator/issues/581)

From what I understand is that you are interested only in models generation. So maybe you should just use directly the Modelina tool that is used there in go-watermill-template.

Modelina is already integrated with [AsyncAPI CLI](https://github.com/asyncapi/cli) and you can do `asyncapi generate models golang asyncapi.yml`

Comment: is there a difference between this CLI and the one that is used in the Docker container asyncapi/generator? Because it seems like the commands differ.

Comment: `asyncapi/generator` CLI will enter deprecation mode soon because we now want to have one `AsyncAPI CLI` for all: generation, conversion, and other stuff. But we will not remove existing docker images, so you can use them. Just at some point, we will stop updating them as `asyncapi/generator` will not have its standalone CLI. does it make sense?

Comment: makes sense. but there is not yet a docker container for the `AsyncAPI CLI`, right?

Comment: no docker yet, looking for help https://github.com/asyncapi/cli/issues/358.

But check if you really need it. This time we want to provide as many alternative ways of installation as possible -> https://github.com/asyncapi/cli#installation

Comment: @JonathanR fyi docker image is now also part of release of the AsyncAPI CLI